# PrimeFaces Layout does not appears

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Working with PrimeFaces 4.0, i include a layout in my page, but it doesn't displayed.

```
<p:layout position="center" id="content"  size="20">
               center
     </p:layoutUnit></p:layout>
```

But, when i remove Layout tag, it works !!!

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center" id="content"  size="20">
               center
            </p:layoutUnit>
```

any idea ?

Comment: Do you have XHTML tags as shown on the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutFull.jsf;jsessionid=1q8thte1v38st95e42wspvuij)?. Something is likely to be overlooked.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
      
      i'm adding bootstrap files maybe it's the reason !!!

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is mixed up. Try this:

```
<p:layout>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="content" size="20">
        center
     </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Comment: i did it but it doesn't displayed at the screen, i'm adding it with a bootstrap layout, !!!